# Integrate Stripe 3d Secure with Ionic 4

Tags: angular, stripe-payments, ionic4, 3d-secure

I'm creating a hybrid App that uses stripe with 3d-Secure cards for payments. What is the best way to achieve it.? What information I need to supply while creating a token for charge.

As of now if I use non-3d secure cards everything works well. I can make the charge but with 3d secure card it fails

I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Stripe\Error\Card: Your card was declined.

```
this.stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_VU9*************1XQfCnP8');
/*This 3d Secure test Card doesn't work  
let card = {    
    number: '4000000000003063',
    expMonth: 12,
    expYear: 2020,
    cvc: '220'
}

console.log (this.stripe.createCardToken(card));
```

3D secure cards on web launch a modal how can I do it on Ionic.
I'm using ionic `native/stripe` (Can move to `stripe.js` if it provides more control)
I'm also using stripe connect but it's fine.

Comment: To trigger stripe 3DS, you would have to create 3DS source instead of using tokens. Follow the step by step instruction here https://stripe.com/docs/sources/three-d-secure#create-source 
Saying all that, Stripe actually has a newer API called PaymentIntent where it will handle 3DS automatically for you (meaning it will show up the 3DS if it is required without any codings), you can take a look at there (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/quickstart).

Comment: Hey @wsw thanks for responding. I can make it work on Angular, but even the paymentintent will launch a popup.. I can use inappbrowser in ionic but don't know how effective it will be and how exactly it will work, will do some testing on my end.

Comment: Looking for a function with ionic stripe native to create source but found nothing as of now.

Comment: @Amit Did you able to get it working with ionic?

Answer (score 2):

[Paulius Nyoumi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7632091/paulius-nyoumi) is right, you should use [payment intents API](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/quickstart) instead of tokenizing your card using the old way.

Also, in order to make this works, you need to allow stripe request, basically adding this code:

```
<allow-navigation href="https://*.stripe.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*.stripe.network/*" />
```

This will let Stripe to create the iframe into your form and handle the different verifications they do.

Comment: **I'm using**
_`<allow-navigation href="https://js.stripe.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*" />`_

**Instead of**

_`<allow-navigation href="https://*.stripe.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*.stripe.network/*" />`_

**Is it risky?**

Answer (score 0):

in oeder to use 3d secure the best way is to move to the new [PaymentIntent api](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/quickstart)

In other words you will use stripe.js in your project.